# Updated installed python module to fix bug, now what?

Tags: python

I was getting this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mutagen/flac.py", line 597, in write
    desc = self.desc.encode('UTF-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I edited the file and changed this line:

```
desc = self.desc.encode('UTF-8')
```

To this:

```
try:                                # 2020-10-18 UnidcodeDecodeError
    desc = self.desc.encode('UTF-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:          # Filename: 06 Surf’s Up.oga
    desc = self.desc                # self.desc already in UTF-8
```

The new code fixed the bug so I reported it on github:

- https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/issues/499

*Hopefully this is the right place to report the bug!*

Then I held the package from upgrades that might wipe out my bug fix:

```
$ apt list | grep mutagen

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

pypy-mutagen/xenial,xenial 1.31-1ubuntu1 all
python-mutagen/xenial,xenial,now 1.31-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
python-mutagen-doc/xenial,xenial 1.31-1ubuntu1 all
python3-mutagen/xenial,xenial 1.31-1ubuntu1 all

$ sudo apt-mark hold python-mutagen

python-mutagen set on hold.
```

Then I wrote the above as requirements in the header of my program.

As this is only my second python program I'm not sure, ***what should I do next?***